# Rails 5.2: New records not saving after upgrade from 5.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I upgraded my Rails 5.1.6 app on Ruby 2.4 to Rails 5.2 on Ruby 2.5.1 by making a new rails 5.2 app then transferring all the app files to it.

I noticed the following changes:

- coffee script stopped working (no problem, I just changed to js)
- creating new records stopped working, but editing existing records was ok. I just get the rollback error below:

  2.5.1 :005 > Item.create(name: "asdf")
     (0.3ms)  BEGIN
     (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK ..

Is there anything in Rails 5.2 that affects new records in Active Record?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem after updating from `5.1.6` to `5.2.2` - did you figure out the problem? It has nothing to do with `optional: true` as far as I can see..

Comment: I didn't upgrade to 5.2.2 because this previous change already gave me headache. I would rather start from scratch as a new 5.2.2 app on the latest Ruby

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `optional: true` has to be set for every belongs_to in Rails 5:

```
belongs_to :another_record, optional: true
```